# How to create trigger for multiple table via one table?

Tags: database, database-design, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, triggers

I have 4 tables :

object:

```
object_id(p.k) | object_type
1              | post
2              | event
```

Like:

```
like_id | uid | object_id | object_type
```

post:

```
post_id | text | like_count
```

event:

```
event_id | name | like_count
```

I want to create a trigger in phpmyadmin which will increase the `like_count` in `post` and `event` table whenever there is an entry in like table.
Whenever a user will like post or event it will get insert to `like` table.
So I want Triggers structure like, if there is insert for `like` table then it should first check if `object_id`=1 then it will update `like_count` of `post` table and if `object_id`=2 then it will update `like_count` of `event` table

Comment: Why keep the counts at all? You can always run a query to `COUNT()` the values (and that query will always be correct - you don't have to worry that the triggers may have worked incorrectly)

Comment: Yes, by using `count()` query it will run, but i want to maintain its record also.